# What are some good Alarms in EBS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am new to AWS Elastic Beanstalk and am wondering what are some good alarms to set? What are the following options and what do they really mean:

- Environment Health
- Target Response Time
- Sum Requests
- CPU Utilization
- Max Network In
- Max Network Out

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following three metrics are [standard EC2 metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/viewing_metrics_with_cloudwatch.html):

- CPU Utilization - The percentage of allocated EC2 compute units that are currently in use on the instance. This metric identifies the processing power required to run an application on a selected instance.
- Network In - The number of bytes received on all network interfaces by the instance. This metric identifies the volume of incoming network traffic to a single instance.
- Network Out - The number of bytes sent out on all network interfaces by the instance. This metric identifies the volume of outgoing network traffic from a single instance.

The other two are [metrics from your ALB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-cloudwatch-metrics.html):

- TargetResponseTime - The time elapsed, in seconds, after the request leaves the load balancer until a response from the target is received. This is equivalent to the target_processing_time field in the access logs.
- RequestCount - The number of requests processed over IPv4 and IPv6. This count includes only the requests with a response generated by a target of the load balancer.

The last one:

- EnvironmentHealth - is custom metric provided by EB and it shows how the health of your EB env, changes with time.

Which alarms to set?

Depends on what your goals are? If you want to be notified or perform some action based on CPU load on your instances, you would use CPU metrics. Similarly for requests or other metrics.

Comment: Hi Marcin! All I want to do with these alarms is to detect any unusual activity. So, maybe if the `TargetResponseTime ` becomes super high (IDK a good threshold though). Any ideas for what kind of thresholds I could put for Network In/Out, given that there are roughly 50 sessions everyday. Thanks! I may be butchering this as I am pretty new to this.

Comment: @NGI Hi :-) Its application specific and usually based on trial-and-error due to lack of past data. You can start 70% of max value for alarm, and observer for a while how it performs. You can always adjust it at any time.

Comment: I see, makes sense that it takes some trial and error. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @NGI No problem. Glad could clarify the metrics :-)

Comment: Marcin, one more thing actually. Do you know what the `Change state after:` question means in EBS when adding an alarm? Thanks!!!

Comment: @NGI Its how many data points are needed for the alarm. If you set alarm with 5 minutes period, and `Change state after: ` will be 15, this means that you need to get 3 points over your threshold for the alarm to tiger (3 x 5 min).

Comment: I see, so is this 3 points in a row? Thanks!

Comment: @NGI yes exactly.

Comment: Got it. One last thing to confirm: If I enter an SNS topic with emails subscribed to it, will it auto email the subscribers when it reaches the alert? Thanks so much for all the help Marcin!

Comment: @NGI Yes, but each subscriber has to enable it. They will get email if you add them to sns topic.